# PHP not respecting non-capturing group with lookahead with a capturing group inside

Tags: php, regex

I have this PHP regex match:

```
 preg_match_all('/(\d+)(?:\.(?=(\d+)))?/', "43.3", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

which (at least in mi mind) means:

```
Match one or more numbers as a group, and if there is a '.' after that
group followed by a group of numbers, match those too, but ignore the '.'.
```

So, possible strings would be:

```
1
23244
24.5
2.454646
```

But not:

```
1.
```

Now, this works perfectly in `regex101.com` with any test string I throw at it, but it doesn't seem to be working with PHP. This is what I get if I `var_dump($matches)`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "43."
    [1]=>
    string(2) "43"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

- Why am I getting the point after the `43`?
- Why am I getting everything duplicated?
- Why am I getting the `3` inside the first group?

Comment: I think `$matches[0][0]` is always the full match, as though your whole pattern was wrapped in a set of parentheses. I don't know how to turn this off.

Comment: Regex101 will explain it for you: https://regex101.com/r/fO4dM5/1

Comment: @JaredFarrish Considering that I mentioned I have tested this with regex101, your comment isn't really helpful. I'm asking here because, obviously, the explanation (and the results) that regex101 is giving me are not the ones that PHP is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first match is always the full match, as though your whole pattern was wrapped in a set of parentheses. I don't think you can turn this off.

You're getting a `3` in the first group because you've got two `(\d+)`'s in your pattern. Remove the parentheses from the one after `?=` if you don't want it.

If you want just the full number, you can try something like this:

```
>>> preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.])/', "43.3 31.52 1.", $matches);
=> 2
>>> $matches
=> [
       [
           "43.3",
           "31.52"
       ]
   ]
```

If there's just one number, you should use `preg_match`, not `preg_match_all`. e.g.

```
>>> preg_match_all('/(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/', "43.3", $matches)
=> 1
>>> $matches
=> [
       [
           "43.3"
       ],
       [
           "43"
       ],
       [
           "3"
       ]
   ]
```

You can always `array_shift` off the full match.

Comment: Your first regex is what I actually wanted to achieve from the beginning. Thank you!

Comment: It actually works better without `PREG_SET_ORDER` :-)

Comment: Oops, this actually fails... kind of. `45.56foo` will match `45.56` too, even when the group after the `.` contains numbers and letters. I need to match only groups of numbers, with an optional `v` or `V` at the beginning.

Comment: It really bugs me that regex101 and PHP are returning different things with exactly the same regex :/

Comment: The `(?![\d.])` bit at the end says that what follows the number must not be another number or a literal `.`. If you want don't want it to match when letters immediately follow then you can try `(?!\S)` which says it won't match if there's a non-space char next. Add `[vV]?` after `(?<!\d)` to allow a leading V.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to apply your logic: https://regex101.com/r/qK5jZ4/1 Can you have a look at it when you can?

Comment: Yup, that works like a charm! Thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

The value in the `[0]` part of the two sub-arrays is the whole string that was matched in each case, then `[1]` and `[2]` are for the capturing groups.

There are two matches overall, and the whole text of the first match was `43.` This is because your regex is saying:

- Match some digits `(\d+)`
- Optionally match by a dot which must be followed by some digits `(?:\.(?=(\d+)))?`

The `43.` part of the string satisfies that, as after the dot is the `3` at the end of the string.

---

It's not perfectly clear from the question, but it sounds like you simply don't want to use the lookahead `(?=…)` at all.

For example, `/(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/` will give the following:

```
// For "43.3"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "43.3"  // whole match
  [1]=>
  string(2) "43"    // first capturing group
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"     // second capturing group
}
// For "1."
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
// For "12345"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "12345"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Though I'm still not sure why regex101 is returning different results than PHP (even when I selected PCRE in regex101).